# Most efficient way in C/C++ to trim extra whitespace except 1 blank for very large data sets

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I am developing a C/C++ function to trim extra whitespace except 1 blank for very large data set. Here is my function:

```
       void  iterative_trim_whitespace(const char* src, char* target){


             bool hitspace(*src = ' ');
             while (*src != '\x0'){
                if (!hitspace){
                    *target++ = *src++;
                } 
                else{
                    src++;
                }
                if (isspace(*src)){
                    hitspace = true;
                }  
                else{

                    hitspace = false;
                }
             }

         }
```

I wrote a recursive function to do the same thing. I can supply it if you wish. However, for very large data with big strings, the recursive function calll stack overhead could be prohibitive. Does anyone know the fastest way to do this in C/C++ ? I am familiar the Standard Template Library and Boost template libraries. However I think native C/C++ would be faster than C++ templates.

Comment: Do you want C or C++? There is no such language as "C/C++". And C++ templates ARE native C++.

Comment: 1) How large is very large? 2) Does the dataset come from a storage device of some sort, or does it always reside in memory?

Comment: I don't know whether i am getting you right or not but spaces can be trimmed in place also. [here](https://github.com/madaan/entire-src/blob/master/c/compiler%20construction/SymbolTable.c) is a sample. Function is called `space squeezer`. Please excuse me if i am wrong.

Comment: What makes you think templates are slow?

Comment: Look into `std::remove_if`. It works on arrays and iterators.

Comment: For very large data - you should assume the string/s is/are coming from disk as stream (or in stream of blocks to be exact). Anything that does a single read and a single write (and assuming two disks, one for read and one for write) will be probably most efficient. **The bottleneck in this case is NOT the code - it is the IO**.

Comment: It's not morning here, 5pm, I'm going home

Comment: "I think native C/C++ would be faster than C++ templates"  Do you have any empirical evidence to support this?  Or it just an urban legend?

Comment: Regardless of the string algorithm used, you can sppedup the process using a pipeline with 3 threads: thread A reads a chunk of data from file, thread B processes data chunk, thread C saves back data chunk. This way you can process a chunk while the next one is fetched from disk/network.

Comment: @axiom, I read your space_squeezer code. It looks very good. However, we cannot use in-place algorithms because we want to preserve the original data. Thank you.

Comment: @amit, copying a 1GB string WILL be both slow and memory hungry. Besides they may well use memory mapped files which are quite fast.

Comment: @JohnDibling: I measured it back in 1998 (VC6, GCC 2.95), and even then there was no statistically significant difference.

Comment: @MSalters:  Yeah, that was really a kind of semi-rhetorical question intended to challenge Frank's beliefs. :)

Comment: @aleguna, Yes, we are using memory mapped files which are quite fast. Thank you.

Comment: @Antoine, Your multithreading idea sounds very good. We are planningto add multitreading later. We are still in the design stage. Thank you.

Comment: @NPE 1) How large is very large? 1 GB strings 2) Does the dataset come from a storage device of some sort, or does it always reside in memory? The dataset can come from  a storage device. for smaller data sets, the data can reside in memory. Thank you.

Comment: @John Dibling, The main problem with Boost templates is not speed, but the software maintenance required for a prospective customer who wants to audit our company's source code before making a purchase decision. Thank you.

Comment: If the dataset is 1GB in size, and comes from disk, you should probably focus on memory consumption and not on the trimming algorithm (any reasonable linear-time algorithm would work just fine).

Comment: @Frank:  OK, that I can understand.  We have a similar issue. But you said, "I think native C/C++ would be faster than C++ templates,"  which goes way beyond just Boost, and includes the Standard Library (what you're referring to as STL) and templates themselves.  You've suggested basically that "templates are slow."  Have I misundertood what you're saying?  If I haven't misunderstood what you're saying, can you tell us why you believe this to be true?

Comment: @John Dibling, I have an appointment in Lexington,MA now. I will check our project director about the BOOST template benchmarks compared to pure C code benchmarks. THank you.

Comment: @NPE, Your point is well taken. We will try to profile memory consumption. Thank you.

Comment: After testing your code, I'm confused: should all spaces be removed from the output, or should it contain "words", with exactly one space between each word?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Please see my revised answer 6 below which I just added. It is only a very minor change. Thank you for your testing.

Comment: @John Dibling, A possible reason pure C code runs faster than STL template string class is because STL C++ template code has to handle many types of exceptions and many demands from many types of users. With pure C code you can focus on just 1 type of requirement instead of 100 requirements. When we look a the STL template code, it is very difficult to trim down to one requirement. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to assume your intent is a little bit different than "trim" would normally imply. "Trim" is usually used to mean removing extra white space from the beginning and/or end of a string, but you seem to mean that each place there's a run of whitespace in the input, you want a single space in the output.

I'm also assuming you're set on a C-like implementation that deals with C-style strings. If that's not a given, then it's going to be a lot simpler and cleaner to just use iterators and standard algorithms.

Assuming that's the case, I think I'd do things more like this:

```
bool copy_word(char *&dest, char const *&src) { 
    while (isspace(*(unsigned char *)src))
        ++src;

    while (*src && *src != ' ') {
        *dest = *src;
        ++dest;
        ++src;
    }
    return *src != '\0';
}

void trim_whitespace(char *dest, char const *src) { 
    while (copy_word(dest, src))
        *dest++ = ' ';
    *dest = '\0';
}
```

There are two major points to keep in mind here: first, when you have a sequence of actions to take (skip white space, then copy non-white space, for example) it's probably cleaner to encode that as a sequence, rather than as different routes through a single loop. Second, when you use `isspace`, you *must*<sup>1</sup> cast the operand to some unsigned type to avoid UB.

Edit: For what it's worth, I put together a little test/benchmark program to see how my code fares vs. the code in the OP's answer.

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void  iterative_trim_whitespace(const char* src, char* target){
    bool firstspace(true);
    while (*src != '\x0'){
        if (firstspace){
            *target++ = *src++;
        } 
        else{
            src++;
        }
        if (firstspace && isspace(*(src - 1))){
            firstspace    = false;
        }  
        else{
            firstspace = true;
        }
    }
    *target = '\x0';
}

struct my_isspace {
    bool operator()(char ch) {
        return ch == ' ' || ch == '\t' || ch == '\n' || ch == '\r' || ch == '\v';
    }
};

bool copy_word(char *&dest, char const *&src) { 
    my_isspace check;
    while (check((*src)))
        ++src;

    while (*src && !check(*src))
        *dest++ = *src++;   
    return *src != '\0';
}

void trim_whitespace(char *dest, char const *src) { 
    while (copy_word(dest, src))
        *dest++ = ' ';
    *dest = '\0';
}

void show(std::string const &label, double t) { 
    std::cout << "Time for " << label << " " << t << " seconds\n";
}

template <class test, class T>
double timer(test t, T a, T b) {
    clock_t start = clock();
    t(a, b);
    clock_t stop = clock();
    return double(stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
}

void generate_string(std::vector<char> &dest, size_t size) { 
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        if (rand() % 5 == 0)
            dest.push_back(' ');
        else
            dest.push_back(rand() % 26 + 'A');
    }
    dest.push_back('\0');
}

int main() {
    static const int size = 1024 * 1024 * 100;

    std::vector<char> src, dest;

    generate_string(src, size-2);

    dest.resize(size);

    show("Original", timer(iterative_trim_whitespace, &src[0], &dest[0]));    
    show("Jerry's", timer(trim_whitespace, &dest[0], &src[0]));

    return 0;
}
```

At least when I run it, I get:

```
Time for Original 0.749 seconds
Time for Jerry's 0.468 seconds
```

I should probably add: as I sort of alluded to in a comment, the implementation of `isspace` on the compiler I'm using is fairly slow, at least compared to the simple one I've thrown in here. In fairness, however, it wouldn't surprise me (much, anyway) if part of the benefit of this is simply being implemented as a function object, which often makes it quite a bit easier for the compiler to generate inline code for it.

For what it's worth, two other points:

1. Microsoft's link-time code generation *slows* both of these quite a bit
2. Either way, the trimming is quite a bit faster than initially generating the input

---

<sup>1</sup> Well, technically, it *is* possible for `char` to be an unsigned type to start with -- but it's unusual enough that you shouldn't count on it. It's also possible for all your input to fall within the ASCII subset of characters that your `char` can probably hold, in which case it'll seem to work just fine -- but that's what's pernicious: you can test it (as much as you want) but until you do so with text that contains characters that are encoded as what will be a negative number as a `char`, it looks fine. Then when your French/Spanish/Norwegian/etc., customer tests it, it falls flat on its face.

Comment: That will check boundary characters (the first after a run of spaces, or non-spaces) twice, and over a large amount of data that's gonna add up.

Comment: @ams: Doubteful. If the data fits in memory, the bottleneck is going to be bandwidth to memory. If it doesn't fit in memory, the bottleneck is going to be bandwidth to disc. The only way the `isspace` becomes significant as a percentage is if the data all fit in cache -- but that limits the data enough that it's doubtful the time for extra calls to `isspace` could add up to a whole millisecond. If you can measure the time for an extra invocation of `isspace` per word, then your library's implementation of `isspace` must be truly horrendous.

Comment: If memory bandwidth were the only bottleneck then there'd be no point in optimizing memcpy and yet those are optimized to hell (and I don't just mean adding prefetch). This code is force to do a byte by byte copy, which is the worst kind, so you want to trim as much out as possible.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Your points are excellent and very useful. We want  to use your ideas for UNICODE UTF-8 strings. Thank you

Comment: Couple of minor nits. This will trim all leading and trailing spaces. Perhaps that's the OP's desire, but it's not specified. Also, I think you want your return statement to be `return *src` (i.e. return 0 when at the end of the string).

Comment: @JimMischel: Yes, that's correct. After running it, I'm actually a bit uncertain about what the original is supposed to do. I thought he intended to copy "words" to the output with exactly one space between them. Testing it, the code actually just skips spaces completely, so it's equivalent to `for (int i=0; i<strlen(src); i++) if (!isspace(src[i]) *dest++ = *src;`

Answer (score 2):

This certainly looks reasonable, and a recursive version would be horrible. If these are large strings I'd consider modifying them in place instead of copying, but that's a higher-level design decision. It doesn't affect speed, but could reduce memory consumption.

Comment: I will check with our project director about whether we can do it in place for large strings. However, if we modified it in place, we would lose our original copy of the the customer's data. Thank you.

Comment: +1:  I agree, you're really not going to do any better than what you already have.  At least not better in terms of algorithmic complexity -- the best you can do is O(n).  There might be a tweak or two but those would be micro-optimzations.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a real quick solution, don't do this at all. Instead have a iterator over input string which skips spaces. Anywhere you need to manipulate a 'trimmed' string just pass this iterator.

This may or may not be possible depending on how far the development has gone by now.

Comment: Good point. Frank, you should tell us more about the context where you need that. Is memory a problem, or time? One problem with the copy-and -delete-blanks is that you don't know beforehand how long the resulting string will be, so do avoid wasting memory you will need to scan the strings twice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code won't work as written. If the first character is a space, then it won't copy the space, and it won't copy the character AFTER the space. Something like this is more reasonable:

```
bool hitSpace = false;
while (*src != '\x0')
{
    if (isspace(*src))
    {
        if (hitSpace)
        {
            src++;
        }
        else
        {
            *target++ = *src++;
            hitSpace = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        *target++ = *src++;
        hitSpace = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think his code works if you replace the single `=` with `==` in the initialization of `hitspace`

Comment: Hmmm, this code tests if `*src` is not nul, and then checks if it is a space. It's probably sufficient to only check for the nul-terminator if it's not a space. The nul-terminator is to most unlikely character in the data.

Comment: @ams: Yes, it might be possible to shave a few cycles from each iteration that is a space. That would make the code somewhat less readable (the nul check is checking for end of string). The important thing is that this code works, whereas the previous code didn't. If you want to squeeze a fraction of a percent of cycles from it, be my guest.

Comment: @Zane: I don't think so. Do a simple walk-through against the string `" Z"` (leading space followed by Z) and see what happens. It looks to me like the code will not write the space because `hitSpace` is true. Then it will get the "Z" and won't output it, either, because `hitSpace` is still true.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would choose iterative (in C or C++) over recursive. The compiler will probably convert a recursive algorithm into a loop anyway, but if it doesn't (or you build in debug mode) then you will overflow your stack for sure. Besides, there's a cost to calling functions and you want to avoid that.

Your basic algorithm looks sound (once the bug Jim spotted is fixed). I would check that `isspace` is being inlined. If not then replace it with `*str == ' '`.

A solution involving templates is surely just complicating a simple problem to no advantage.

Comment: I will check if isspace is inlined on Windows , GCC, and Solaris UNIX compiler and IBM AIX compiler. Thank you.

Comment: In MIcrosoft Visual C++ 9.0, isspace is inlined -- extern __inline int (__cdecl isspace) ( int c ) { if (__locale_changed == 0) { return __fast_ch_check(c, _SPACE); } else { return (_isspace_l)(c, NULL); } }. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Jerry Coffin, I just got back from appointment from Lexington. This version has been tested. I apologize for the first version which I hastily wrote in a rush to get to my dentist in Lexington.

```
void  iterative_trim_whitespace(const char* src, char* target){

         bool firstspace(true);
         while (*src != '\x0'){
            if (firstspace){
                *target++ = *src++;
            } 
            else{
                src++;
            }
            if (firstspace && isspace(*(src - 1))){
      firstspace    = false;
            }  
            else{
      firstspace = true;
            }
         }
    *target = '\x0';
}
```

---

```
void iterative_trim_whitespace_revised(const char* src, char* target){
    bool firstspace(true);
    int ct(0);
    while (*src != '\x0'){
        if (firstspace){
            *target++ = *src++;
        } 
        else{
            src += ct - 2; 
        }
        if (firstspace){ 
            char *x = (char *)src - 1;
            ct = 1;
            bool sentinel(false);
            while(isspace(*(x + (ct - 1)))){
                ct += 1;
                sentinel = true;

            }
            if (sentinel){
                firstspace = false;
            }
        }
        else{
            ct = 1;
            firstspace = true;
        }
    }
    *target = '\x0';
}
```

---

void  iterative_trim_whitespace_friday_5Timesfaster(const char* src, char* target){
        bool firstspace(true);
        int ct(0);
             while (*src != '\x0'){
                if (firstspace){
                    *target++ = *src++;
                } 
                else{
         src += ct - 2; 
           }

```
       if (firstspace){ 
     char *x = (char *)src - 1;
     ct = 1;
     bool sentinel(false);
     while(*(x + (ct - 1)) == ' '){ 
         ct += 1;
         sentinel = true;

     }
     if (sentinel){
         firstspace    = false;
     }
            }
            else{
     ct = 1;
     firstspace = true;
            }
         }
    *target = '\x0';
```

}

// Here is our ProjectDirector's version  from this morning
// TrimLeading() and TrimTrailing are additional inline functions

void  iterative_trim_whitespace_ProjectDirector(const char* src, char* target){

```
int out=0;

for (int i=0;src[i]!= '\x0';i++) {

    if (src[i] != ' ' || src[i+1] != ' '){

        target[out++]=src[i];
    }

}

target[out]= '\x0';
```

}

Comment: Pretty sure this still isn't what you want -- it loses the first non-whitespace character of most words.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, My test shows that src = "AAA  BBB  CCC" is transformed into "AAA BBB CCC". Could you please tell me the string that is causing the loss of the first non-whitespace character of most words? Thank you.

Comment: The input I used that showed the problem was: "HGUEY  FX RVCGBK QUWN ZSTJRPGRNVS  CSYQ  I FMNMK". The result I got was: "HGUEY FX VCGBK UWN STJRPGRNVS CSYQ I MNMK". Looking again, I guess that probably doesn't qualify as most words, but almost certainly too many anyway.

Comment: void  iterative_trim_whitespace(const char* src, char* target){     bool firstspace(true);
int ct(0);
while (*src != '\x0'){
      if (firstspace){
             *target++ = *src++;
      } 
      else{
             src += ct - 2; 
      }

      if (firstspace){ 
 char *x = (char *)src - 1;
 ct = 1;
 bool sentinel(false);
 while(isspace(*(x + (ct - 1)))){
   ct += 1;
   sentinel = true;
 
 }
 if (sentinel){
   firstspace    = false;
 }
      }
      else{
 ct = 1;
 firstspace = true;
      }
    }  *target = '\x0';
}

Comment: The revised version seems to work -- but it's about half the speed of the one I posted above.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Thank you for taking all the time to answer and test your answer.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Your answer and timing analysis would make a great interview question for C++ software engineers. Thank you.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin, Your testing was very thorough. This function even handles leading and trailing whitespace. Second, isspace is inlined in Microsoft Visual Studio C++ 9.0. Thank you for all of your assistance yesterday. --- extern __inline int (__cdecl isspace) ( int c ) { if (__locale_changed == 0) { return __fast_ch_check(c, _SPACE); } else { return (_isspace_l)(c, NULL); } }

Comment: Good Friday Morning, Here is the project Director's version which we just profiled using Jerry Coffin's test program. Thank you.